# ShaderProgram.loadShader generates a NullPointerException (new post from old one)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, libgdx, shader

Old post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616270/shaderprogram-loadshader-throws-nullpointerexception.

I'm basically having the same trouble as the guy in the following link: Libgdx shader setup NullPointerException. Yet I'm trying to launch this on my desktop instead of an Android Virtual Emulator. Is there a way i can enable OpenGl ES 2.0 on my desktop?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.loadShader(ShaderProgram.java:194)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.compileShaders(ShaderProgram.java:173)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.<init>(ShaderProgram.java:156)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ImmediateModeRenderer20.createDefaultShader(ImmediateModeRenderer20.java:233)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ImmediateModeRenderer20.<init>(ImmediateModeRenderer20.java:56)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.<init>(ShapeRenderer.java:116)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.<init>(ShapeRenderer.java:111)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.<init>(ShapeRenderer.java:107)
    at View.Maze.<init>(Maze.java:20)
    at com.ratmazesprint.game.RatMazeSprintGame.<init>(RatMazeSprintGame.java:14)
    at com.ratmazesprint.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:14)
```

Here is where the code crashes:

```
SpriteBatch batch;
    ShapeRenderer renderer;

public Maze(){

    --> renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        cam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        cam.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2, 0);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        touchPos = new Vector3();
        position = new Vector2(1, 1); 

        //this.cam = new OrthographicCamera(10, 7);
        //this.cam.update();
        //drawGrid();
        //this.model = model;
        model.addObserver(this);
    }
```

Comment: LibGDX isn't initialized yet in the constructor. Use the `create` method instead.

Comment: @ Xoppa: Dude, you're a hero :)!! It works. Thanks!!!